# CSS Overlay with pseudo element

Tags: html, css

How do I create a CSS overlay with an pseudo element?

```
.modal {
     position:fixed;
     top:100px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     left:0;
     right:0;
     width:500px;
     display:none;
     border:2px solid #736D61;
     background:#fff;
     padding:10px;
}
.modal:after {
     position:fixed;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

I have tried this but it's not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It probably isn't working because [the pseudo-element isn't generated if the `content` value is omitted](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content). The default `content` value is `none`, which is likely why you aren't seeing the pseudo element. Therefore you need to specify a value other than `none` for the `content` property:

```
.modal:after {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

It's also worth mentioning that since a pseudo element is essentially added as a child element, it will be positioned above the `.modal` element since a stacking context is established. To work around that, you could add a `:before` pseudo element to the `.modal` element's parent like this:

```css
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 500px;
  border: 2px solid #736D61;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.modal-overlay:before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-overlay">
  <div class="modal">MODAL</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked! But it's overlaying the modal. How can I fix that?

Comment: @JasonDeClau The problem is that a pseudo element is essentially added as a child element. This means that it will be positioned above the `.modal` element since a stacking context is established. To work around that, you could add a `:before` pseudo element to a parent wrapper element like in this example - https://jsfiddle.net/63ockpds/

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to use border-box. No pseud-classes needed :

```
.modal {
  background-color: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 9999px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  padding: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  
  z-index: 999;   
}
```

[**Codepen example**](https://codepen.io/dragoeco/pen/BayaBor)

It works also with outline :

```
outline: 9999px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
```

Quick and easy ^^

Comment: That is hilariously effective and unintrusive. Thanks for this beautiful solution!